# understanding some JQuery syntax

Tags: jquery

I need some help underestanding some JQUery code, have tried googling but not found anything plus I don't
know exactly what to google!  (it may be thatthe lines I refer to may be some JQuery extension).

JSP

```
<div id="sugar-opts">

    <div class="howmanysugars">
    <label>How many <span id="sugar-label">sugars</span>?
    :



    <div class="numSugarsDiv">

        <input type="text" name="num-sugars" id="num-sugars" placeholder="?" value="1" />

        <button class="btn minus">-</button>
        <button class="btn plus">+</button>
    </div>

    :

    <div>
        <label class="clearfix sugarLabel" >Include sugar? </label>

        <label><input type="radio" name="include-sugar" value="yes" /> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="include-sugar" value="no" /> No</label>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$sugarOptsContainer = $('#sugar-opts');


Event handler:
$('input[name=include-sugar]', $sugarOptsContainer)     // first part refers to <input element,
                                                        // but what is the purpose of: , $sugarOptsContainer

.data('root', $('> :last-child', $sugarOptsContainer))  // this defines jquery object 'root' but what is the meaning
                                                        // of  > :last-child, and again purpose of , $sugarOptsContainer
.on('change', handleSugarChange);                       // defines function called on onChange event





function handleSugarChange(event) {

    var $root = $(this).data('root');                // this refer to 'root' defined above

    if ($('.radio.selected', $root).length) {        // checks if radio is selected, but why $root, and 
                                                     // what is purpose of .length here? 

    $root.removeClass('error');
        formData.sugar = this.value;
    return;

    } else {

    $root.addClass('error');

    }

    displayMessage();
}
```

Comment: `$('input[name=include-sugar]', $sugarOptsContainer)` is equivalent to `$sugarOptsContainer.find('input[name=include-sugar]')`

Answer (score 2):

In this:

```
$sugarOptsContainer = $('#sugar-opts');
$('input[name=include-sugar]', $sugarOptsContainer)
```

`$sugarOptsContainer` is a context in which to search so it looks for those types of input tags only within that hierarchy.  It is basically the same as:

```
$('#sugar-opts').find('input[name=include-sugar]');
```

---

In this:

```
$('> :last-child', $sugarOptsContainer)
```

This is finding the last child of each child of `$sugarOptsContainer`.  The `>` finds all children and then `:last-child` finds the last child of each of those children.

As in the previous example, I prefer to write it as:

```
$sugarOptsContainer.find('> :last-child');
```

---

In this:

```
if ($('.radio.selected', $root).length)
```

The `.length` check is checking to see if there are any items in the jQuery object.  If the jQuery object is empty, `.length` will be zero and the `if` check will fail.  If the jQuery object is not empty, then `.length` will be non-zero and teh `if` condition will be met.  So, it's like this:

```
// if there are any select items
if ($('.radio.selected', $root).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=include-sugar]', $sugarOptsContainer)
```

This is the same as (and, personally, I prefer the following)

```
$sugarOptsContainer.find('input[name=include-sugar]')
```

Again,

```
$('> :last-child', $sugarOptsContainer) // is the same as
$sugarOptsContainer.find('> :last-child')
```

And

```
if ($('.radio.selected', $root).length) {
```

is

```
if (!!$root.find('.radio.selected').length)
```

There, I (unnecessarily) coerce the `.length` to a boolean using `!!`. Basically, it's just checking if anything matches `'.radio.selected'`. `if` statements coerce the test expression to a boolean anyways, so the `!!` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sugarOptsContainer = $('#sugar-opts');
```

This for selecting an element called sugar-opts and hold the result in variable named $sugarOptsContainer

```
$('input[name=include-sugar]', $sugarOptsContainer)
```

Here $(children, Parent)  get the inputs which has name include-sugar  which inside $sugarOptsContainer which is element with id sugar-opts

```
.data('root', $('> :last-child', $sugarOptsContainer))
```

.data is used when you do something like that   will select the value in data attribute

```
:last-child
```

for example if you have table with more than tr as

```
<table> 
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

:last will select the last tr for you and also :first will select first child for that table for you 
but here

```
$('> :last-child', $sugarOptsContainer)
```

it will select the last child inside $sugarOptsContainer

```
.on('change', handleSugarChange);
```

.on is used to bind an event to that element .on(Eventname, action which will handle the event)
when this input change it will call the function handleSugarChange

inside the function

```
var $root = $(this).data('root');
```

this is for the input which change which cause this function to be called

```
.data('root');
```

as before is to select attribute named data for that element which is the input which trigger change.

```
$('.radio.selected', $root).length
```

when radio button is selected what i think is selected class will be added to this input and then when you say .radio.selected that mean get the radio which selected which is inside the $root as refer above $(children, parent) 
if this is any input with this 2 classed then length will not be 0 and will enter if condition if no input match then will enter else

```
$root.addClass('error');
```

addClass and removeClass is jquery functions to add and remove class from element.

I hope i explain all related jQuery in this part.